# Extract attachment from email msg, rename and save

Tags: python

```
import extract_msg
import dateutil.parser as dparser

email_path = ... #ie. location of email messages
save_path = ... #ie. where to save attachments

for i, file in enumerate(files):
    path = join(email_path,file)
    msg = extract_msg.Message(path)
    attachments = msg.attachments
    date = dparser.parse(msg.date).strftime("%m/%d/%Y").replace('/','-')

    for f in attachments:
        f.save(customPath=save_path)
```

How can I rename the attachments when I save? I tried passing a 'filename' argument, but the filename doesn't change. Attachments can potentially have the same name so I would like to add pass the date to the end of the filename

Comment: Is this based on the [extract-msg](https://pypi.org/project/extract-msg/) package?

Comment: The parameter name should be [**`customFilename`**](https://github.com/TeamMsgExtractor/msg-extractor/blob/master/extract_msg/attachment.py#L104) not **`customPath`**. I have never heard of or used this library before, so just searched up the documentation and the source code.

Comment: yes it's extract_msg package

Comment: Missing the definition of `save_path`, where is the _date_ added? Called method `f.save()` and from your mentioned tests it seems this does save attachments correctly, but with a filename that you didn't expect or want. Debug print the filename before saving and add a link to the docs of this `save()` method, so we can clarify how to apply it?

Comment: customFilename was the solution. However, in order to call the file name, I had to use f.longFilename which outputs the full filename including the type. So had to split up the string and insert the date in the middle. Not ideal, but gets the job done

Comment: If you have an answer to the question you originally posed, you should include it in the *Answers* section below, not in the body of your original post (which is reserved solely for the question itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for f in attachments:
   name = str(f.longFilename).split('.')[0]
   f_type = str(f.longFilename).split('.')[1]
   filename = f"{name}_{date}.{f_type}"
   f.save(customPath=save_path, customFilename=filename)
```

Comment: Python has a function to split the filename and extension, [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext). You could use it like `name, f_type = splitext(f.longFilename)`